# Block render array image_formatter

Tags: 7, blocks

How can I pass a renderable array from within a block?

```
$block['content'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_formatter',
  '#variables' => array('path' => 'hello.png'),
);
```

How do I pass the variables that image_formatter needs when I use a renderable array from within a block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$image = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_formatter',
  '#image_style' => 'thumbnail',
  '#item' => array(
    'uri' => $user->picture->uri,
    'alt' => '',
    'title' => '',
  ),
);
$block['image'] = $image;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit confusing until you've done it a couple of times (it had me scratching my head for ages); you need to prefix the names of the variables with a `#`, as properties of the array:

```
$block['content'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_formatter',
  '#path' => 'hello.png',
  '#alt' => 'Hello!'
);
```

That would be the equivalent of:

```
theme('image_formatter', array('path' => 'hello.png', 'alt' => 'Hello!'));
```

Comment: The above throws this error at me Recoverable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to l() must be an array, string given, called in .../modules/image/image.field.inc on line 633 and defined in l() (line 2340 of ../includes/common.inc).

Comment: How strange, I was just about to comment on this...my answer has the wrong variable names for `theme_image_formatter()`, @milkovsky's answer is spot on