# How renderable array for an image with style should look like?

Tags: media, theming

I have a custom module that outputs some images. Now, I would like to render them properly.

Currently, I use [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) function, kinda similarly to the way shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11149043/2389310)<sup>1</sup> and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/68385/16495)<sup>1</sup>:

```
echo theme('image_style', array(
  'path' => $image['uri'],
  'style_name' => 'product_page_thumbnail',
  'attributes' => array(
    'alt' => $image['ImageAlt'],
    'title' => $image['ImageTitle'],
  )
));
```

Now, the [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) docs says:

> Avoid calling this function directly. It is preferable to replace direct calls to the [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) function with calls to [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) by passing a render array with a #theme key to [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7), which in turn calls [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7).

So how would I do that?

I know renderable array for links, it's as simple as:

```
$link = array(
  '#type'    => 'link',
  '#title'   => $title,
  '#href'    => 'http://example.com',
  '#options' => array('html' => TRUE, 'title' => 'link'),
);
```

So I want the same, but for images. Somehow I can't find any documented example of it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Internal Stack Exchange links, just for reference.

Comment: I'm in the process of experimenting now, as search failed me miserably, resulting with either direct calls to `theme()` I want to avoid, or with even more crude way of directly concatenating parts of `<img>` tag in tpl file, what I want to avoid even more.

Comment: ha Molot your question is dup now http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68381/render-array-with-images

Comment: @Bala Nope, there guy wants to render link with image in it. I want to render image on it's own.

Comment: what if you create you own element type with hook_element_info()?

Comment: @xurshid29 It will work, but I'm pretty sure there is image element already and I just need to find out how to use it. After all, if theme can work, probably high-level functions can, too.

Comment: @Mołot I don't think that there is an image element.. Because theme_image() function itself uses somekind of `$attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path'])` and `return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />'` lines...

Comment: @xurshid29 but `render()` is supposed to call `theme()`, so it's OK for `theme()` to return concatenated bits.

Comment: `$render = array(
    '#theme' => 'image',
    '#path' => $file->uri,
  );

  return render($render);` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block render array image\_formatter](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30677/block-render-array-image-formatter)

Comment: @milkovsky usually the more specific questions are closed as duplicates of more generic ones, or ones with lower scores as duplicates of higher ones. Age does not matter much, unless one question was asked recently. But oh well. I won't lose any rep if this will get closed, or anything. In 2013 your vote might really help me ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing specific for images, but there is for *any* theme function. Your old code using `theme()` would be equivalent to:

```
$build = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_style',
  '#path' => $image['uri'],
  '#style_name' => 'product_page_thumbnail',
  '#alt' => $image['ImageAlt'],
  '#title' => $image['ImageTitle'],
);
```

Basically you pass the named variables for the theme function as `#`-prefixed properties, and the render system will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, copy-paste worked, now I just need to move things where they belong :)

Comment: I believe in Drupal 8, `#path` has now become `#uri`