# Render image from $node - no image style applied

Tags: media

I read tons of solutions how to render an image in a `PHP`template where I have the whole node in `$content`, however I don't get how to render it using a `$node` object, including the given image style etc.

So I got all the code working and can access the node title for example via:

```
$node->title
```

How do I generate the proper `HTML` for this node (in this example the machine tag is `field_slideshow_image`)?

This line does not work, it gives me a 404 for the image URL:

```
<img src="<?php print image_style_url('slideshow', $node->field_slideshow_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" />
```

however, it contains at least the name of the actual image…

Update:

I found out that I have to force an image creation if there was none before, so now it works using:

```
$image_uri      = $node->field_slideshow_image['und'][0]['uri']; // or any public://my_image
$style = 'slideshow';
$derivative_uri = image_style_path($style, $image_uri);
$success        = file_exists($derivative_uri) || image_style_create_derivative($style, $image_uri, $derivative_uri);

$new_image_url  = file_create_url($derivative_uri);
echo $new_image_url."<br /><br />";
echo "<img class=\"slideshow_image\" src=\"".$new_image_url."\" />";
```

However, the image style "slideshow" does not get applied! I tried it with the default "thumbnail" and that one works well.

Comment: Well, what is in `$node->field_slideshow_image`, eg, if you throw in a `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($node->field_slideshow_image, TRUE) . '</pre>');` what information do you have to work with?  Then just make sure you are sending a path to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved the 404 problem and updated my post.

Comment: Why don't you use just `<?php print render($content['field_slideshow_image']); ?>`?

Comment: In first line 404 is hard to explain. Anyway, you should not need to manually echo img tag. See [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/97763/16495) if you need finer control than the command @ЕлинЙ. provided allows.