# image style not applied porgrammatically

Tags: media

I create below function to create image style programmatically

```
function imh_get_image_from_uri($image_uri, $style) {
    $derivative_uri = image_style_path($style, $image_uri);
    $success = file_exists($derivative_uri) || image_style_create_derivative($style, $image_uri, $derivative_uri);
    $new_image_url = file_create_url($derivative_uri);
    return theme_image(array('path' => $new_image_url));
}
```

and call in my tpl with

```
 imh_get_image_from_uri($node->field_cast_image['und'][0]['uri'],'215x317');
```

and  a example of image created path is

`http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/styles/215x317/public/Hugh%20Jackman-2.jpg`

I check the images style , as expamle this image image style  set  to scale `215` * `317`,every thing seems work good but when I see image directly I see the image in this path not resized ( I call my function with another image style but also they are not resize or scale or ....) ,
The images that use build-in drupal image style work correctly but when I use top function to load image style programmatically the image style action (resize, scale ,... ) not applied, the image create on that path but noting applied on it.

where is problem?

**update**
Also I try

```
$build = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_style',
  '#path' => $image_uri,
  '#style_name' => $style,
    );
return render($build);
```

**output**
`<img src="http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/styles/215x317/public/Hugh%20Jackman-2.jpg?itok=PcP0uFjT" width="215" height="317">`

but the problem exists yet, the file in the image path exists but not resized.
it seems change it by style ( not resized main image)

Comment: image_style_create_derivative expects path to image, not full URL. Are you sure you feed this function with proper data? And why don't you just prepare a [renderable array for image](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/97769/16495)?

Comment: @Mołot ,I am not sure that this function work correctly, can you help that how can I get image style from uri of file and specified image style?

Comment: @Mołot I see your question, and try something like it but the problem exists, the image not resized

Comment: Well, if renderable array way does not work for you either, then I have no idea. It worked for me all right.

Comment: @Mołot I found solution ,I should delete previous  image created, they prevent to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
  return  theme('image_style',array('style_name' => $style, 'path' => $image_uri));
```

but this not work first because the image style for that file created before , first I should remove it then try this  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This solved my issue, maybe it can help you out.

```
$image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
$image_output = render(field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $image[0],
array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'medium', 'label' => ''))));                   

print render($image_output);
```