# How to insert HTML that includes an ampersand>

Tags: blocks

I've created a custom block, and I'm trying to get this custom block to output a specific piece of HTML. The HTML needs to be different on every page, because it needs to include the page's URL in it. For instance, if the page is http://www.businesskorea.co.kr/article/7789/content-business-marginalized-samsung-reorganizes-media-solution-center-owing-poor, then the block should output:

```
<img src="http://cp.news.search.daum.net/api/publish.json?nurl={http%3A%2F%2Fwww.businesskorea.co.kr%2Farticle%2F7789%2Fcontent-business-marginalized-samsung-reorganizes-media-solution-center-owing-poor}&xml_url={http%3A%2F%2Fwww.businesskorea.co.kr%2Farticle%2F7789%2Fcontent-business-marginalized-samsung-reorganizes-media-solution-center-owing-poor%3Fformat%3Dxml}&channel=business" style="display:none;">
```

This is to be compatible with daum.net's news publishing functionality. The code that I've written up for this custom block looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/

function bkcustom_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['bkcustom_daum_json_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('BKCustom Daum JSON'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
* Implements hook_block_view().
*/

function bkcustom_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'bkcustom_daum_json_block':
      $block['subject'] = '';
      $block['content'] = BKCUSTOM_DAUM_JSON_BLOCK_CONTENT();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function BKCUSTOM_DAUM_JSON_BLOCK_CONTENT() {
  $path_alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["q"]);

  $encoded_path_alias = urlencode($path_alias);

  $output = t("<img src=\"http://cp.news.search.daum.net/api/publish.json?nurl={http%3A%2F%2Fwww.businesskorea.co.kr%2F" . $encoded_path_alias . "}&xml_url={http%3A%2F%2Fwww.businesskorea.co.kr%2F" . $encoded_path_alias . "%3Fformat%3Dxml}&channel=business\" style=\"display:none;\" />");

  return $output;
}
```

Which outputs almost, but not quite, what I need. The output changes ampersands to `&amp;`, and somehow deletes the final forward slash (/) at the end of the IMG tag. The output looks like this:

```
<img src="http://cp.news.search.daum.net/api/publish.json?nurl={http%3A%2F%2Fwww.businesskorea.co.kr%2Farticle%2F7789%2Fcontent-business-marginalized-samsung-reorganizes-media-solution-center-owing-poor}&amp;xml_url={http%3A%2F%2Fwww.businesskorea.co.kr%2Farticle%2F7789%2Fcontent-business-marginalized-samsung-reorganizes-media-solution-center-owing-poor%3Fformat%3Dxml}&amp;channel=business" style="display:none;">
```

The most frustrating part of this exercise is that if I delete the opening and closing brackets, <>, the code works perfectly and prints out each character exactly as I need it to. That's how I tested to see if it would work. But when I introduce opening and closing brackets, the code changes and the JSON query or whatever the crap this is fails.

How can I preserve the & and / characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by abandoning the custom module idea and doing the work in the theme layer - in node.tpl.php. I should have done that from the beginning I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`t` function is for texts, not for HTML, so it is perfectly allowed to fail. Also, you should not use dynamic strings in `t`'s first argument at all, it is meant to be static.

Whenever possible, you should use [renderable arrays](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/97763/16495). In your specific case this seems a bit difficult, so first thing to, if you are willing to settle for quick and dirty, do would be just forget `t` and output tag directly.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to get back to this until now. When I remove the `t`, the output remains the same. ampersands are converted into `&amp;`. I'm going to look into renderable arrays.